# How to update the background color of a combobox in PySimpleGUI?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I want to be able to change the background of a combobox to red to indicate to the user that they forgot to select an option. I can change the background color of a text field, but not a combobox, as seen below, in the minimum reproducible example.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

test_layout = [[sg.Combo([1, 2, 3], key="combo"), sg.Text("Name", key="text")]]

window = sg.Window(
    "Test",
    test_layout,
    location=(0, 0),
)


while True:
    event, values = window.read(timeout=5)

    window["combo"].Widget.config(background="red")
    window["text"].Widget.config(background="red")
```

Is there a different way to update the background of the combobox?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For entry field in the `Combo` element, ttk style required here

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 40))

layout = [
    [sg.Combo([1, 2, 3], background_color='blue', text_color='white', key="combo"),
     sg.Text("Name", key="text")],
    [sg.Button('Update')],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)
combo = window['combo']

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Update':
        combo_style = combo.ttk_style
        style_name  = combo.widget["style"]
        # style_name = combo.ttk_style_name if PySimpleGUI version 4.61.0.160
        combo_style.configure(style_name, foreground='yellow', fieldbackground='red')
window.close()
```

Update to new version from Github

> 4.61.0.162
>
> Addition of new parms to Combo.update - text color, background color.  Also font now applied correctly to dropdown list

Then, you can do it like

```py
    elif event == 'Update':
        window["combo"].update(text_color='yellow', background_color='red')
```

Comment: Is it possible to make this work for a readonly combobox?

Comment: A new version on PySimpleGUI Repo has some changes for combobox if you care to try that one.  Not released to pypi so must download from GitHub.

Comment: @Cemos121 It should work the same for a `readonly=True` Combo element.